# git: how to revert the operation of moving one branch to another if it has been already pushed and it does not exist in the log

Tags: git

Let's say I have two branches:

- branch: master
- branch: branchX

I wanted to move the files of branchX to master. Then delete branchX. I typed (**I did not used merge**, unfortunately):

```
git branch -f master branchX
git push REMOTE_GIT_URL branchX master
```

Unfortunately the result was the opposed than expected: branchX has the content of master now. I have typed `git log`, but it does not show any of these operations.

Which command was wrong? Should I use the command `merge` instead? How to revert it?

Note: I did not trusted myself, so I downloaded a zipped copy of branchX previously. Anyway I want to learn what I did wrong!

Comment: *move branchX to master* what exactly do you mean

Comment: I'd recommend not using the **`--force`** flag unless you know what you're doing. The need of `-f` is a hint to you that you'd destroy something if you continue.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I updated the question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Thanks @eckes for your recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the work done in `branchX` into `master`, this is called **merging**. You want to merge `branchX` into `master`.

In that case you need to:

- checkout `master`: `git checkout master`
- merge `branchX` into it: `git merge branchX`

Once this is correct locally (and only then), you can push your newly updated `master` to your remote repo:

- `git push REMOTE_GIT_URL master` (with your local `master` still checked out)

As you write, `branchX` is not needed anymore, since its work is integrated to `master`. You can clean by:

- deleting the local branch: `git branch -d branchX`. This should work with no warning, otherwise you have changes in `branchX` that were not integrated and would be lost by deleting the branch.
- deleting the branch on your remote as well: `git push REMOTE_GIT_URL :branchX`. Note the syntax, you are pushing *nothing* (left side of the `:`) on to remote `branchX`, this is how you delete branches on remotes. Only do this after you have pushed `master`, so that the remote also has the new `master` where `branchX` is integrated.

Comment: Thank you! It is very helpful (so I voted the answer up). However, I guess I should not mark it as the accepted answer because it does not answer the question :/